# Is there a type for Mirage.js's schema when working with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, miragejs

Am using **mirage.js** to mock an API that's not complete using **typescript in strict mode**. I am having trouble with the schema type in the `routes()` method.

**It works**, I just want to avoid the warning that comes with using `any` as the type.

A simple "endpoint" in the routes method

```js
routes () {
  this.get(`todos`, (schema: any) => {
    return schema.todos.all();  
  });
}
```

I also tried to de structure the schema and getting the *todos* like so:

```js
routes () {
  this.get(`todos`, ({ todos }) => {
    return todos.all();  
  });
}
```

But I didn't managed to find the type the *todos* should have.

Is there any solution to this issue other than using `any`?

#### Edit

A working codesandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-5-typescript-forked-57h03m?file=/src/App.vue

Check folder named miragejs to see a more complete version of my code.

Comment: What is the class? Do you have a minimal reproduction? Would be nice if we had the entire class.

Comment: @hhearts mmmm. What do you mean with the entire class?

Comment: You need to share more code so we can find a solution faster. We don't know what this.get is, for example.

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to redefine the types of your API in your frontend code base (maybe mirage.js can provide you a `.d.ts` file). So define them like `interface Todo { id: number; description: string; }`. Then (I'm not sure as you share only the minimal code base) but you could pass it as a generic like `this.get<Todo[]>(...)`. Probably the `schema` will be then typed accordingly. This is just supposition so please provide a working example with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for example.

Comment: @johannchopin Just added the codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your typescript linter's configuration.
You might remove the rule "typedef: arrow-parameter" in your `tslint.json`
Rules are explicitly declared, if you want to keep other benefits from the typedef rule, you will have to list them all, here's the one I personnaly use :

```
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    ...
    "typedef": [
      true,
      "call-signature",
      "parameter",
      "arrow-parameter", // Remove me
      "property-declaration",
      "variable-declaration",
      "variable-declaration-ignore-function",
      "member-variable-declaration",
      "object-destructuring",
      "array-destructuring"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's the [link](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/) to the documentation of typedef rule